# Django template render from db and interprets tags

Tags: django, templates, tags, rendering

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^/mailing/(?P<pk>\d+)/preview/$', PreView.as_view(), name="preview"),
```

**models.py**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    # ... other fields ...
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"), help_text=_("You can use Django <a target='_blank' href='https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/'>template tags</a>"))
```

**views.py**

```
class PreView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "mailing/preview.html"

    def get_context_data(self, pk, **kwargs):
        try:
            return {"message": Message.objects.get(id=pk)}
        except Message.DoestNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

**template/mailing/preview.html**

```
<div id="body">{{ message.body|safe }}</div>
```

however django templatetags are not interpreted, only rendered as a string.
I would like to use a

```
{% now "Y-m-d" %}
```

tag in message body. In future there will be need to use any other tag.

I have managed two working approaches, both of them are not satisfying me.

- Use regexps and substitutions,
- Put whole template source in db TextField (insted of file), and renders a page(template) from it.

I am also thinking about creating templatetag which returns a rendered template out of **Message.body**. However I am not quite sure whether it will be good or wrong.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use [Django template system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system)

```
from django.template.loader import get_template_from_string
from django.template.context import Context

return {"message": message, "body": get_template_from_string(message.body).render(Context())}
```

EDIT:

Alternative (and prettier) solution can be custom template filter:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def render(value):
    return get_template_from_string(value).render(Context())
```

and use:

```
{{message.body|render}}
```

Comment: I did exactly the same in my previous project. I was hoping that there is a more elegant way to do it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I like the templatetag version!

Comment: Better to use `Template(value)` instead of undocumented `get_template_from_string(value)`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383194/what-is-the-difference-between-loader-get-template-from-string-and-creating-a)