# What is the difference between loader.get_template_from_string() and creating a Template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been working on a means for users to store their own templates and I know that I'm going to have to create Templates on the fly. For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template
>>> Template("Testing {{test}}")
<django.template.base.Template object at 0x10c58f990>
```

However, when I asked about loading template strings, I was advised to use `get_template_from_string`:

```
>>> from django.template import loader
>>> loader.get_template_from_string("Testing {{test}}")
<django.template.base.Template object at 0x10c8b5450>
```

What is the difference between the two methods? Is one way more pythonic, or preferred to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Django documentation for the templating code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) describes using the first method you've described: using `Template()`.

It does not mention `get_template_from_string`, nor does anywhere else in the documentation.

I would therefore lean heavily on usage of the first method, because the other is presumably more likely to change in future, as it is an undocumented function.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Django, get_template_from_string just instantiates a new template in the same way you do.

```
def get_template_from_string(source, origin=None, name=None):
"""
Returns a compiled Template object for the given template code,
handling template inheritance recursively.
"""
    return Template(source, origin, name)
```

Source code is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader.py

Comment: While it is helpful to know that the source just returns a template, I was looking for an answer with a bit more of an explanation as to why this is :/