# How to interpret/render template tags as HTML from Django database

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to add posts with images from Django admin site, but the safe/autoescape-off filter cannot interpret Django's template tags.

My input and page look like:
[image]
[image]

"copy image address" gives http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'post/image.jpg'%20%%7D

My view inherits from a generic ListView.

My base.html and post_list.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="color: red;">
      <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a>
      {% block contents %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

{% extends 'post/base.html' %}
{% block contents %}
{% for post in object_list %}
  {% autoescape off %}{{ post.text }}{% endautoescape %}
  {{ post.text|safe }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you probably did not define the `TEMPLATE` settings in your config

Comment: I only specified 'DIR' and left other settings as default, what is the one that I need to define here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're trying to do directly in the template. Django templates are made up of "nodes" that are later resolved into strings. Nodes using the `{{ variable }}` syntax always return a string: even if you use the `safe` filter, Django will not try to convert your `post.text` string into nodes to be rendered by the templating engine.

You could potentially work around this in the view by manually rendering your text as a Django template:

```
from django.template import Template

class MyListView(ListView):

    #...your existing code

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for post in context["object_list"]:
            post.rendered_text = Template(post.text).render(context)
        return context
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {{ post.rendered_text|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

But beware! This is a pretty bad idea from a security standpoint! The `safe` tag is already quite dangerous because it allows cross-site scripting attacks: anyone who has access to create a post can inject malicious Javascript that is displayed to the user. This extra rendering step is even more dangerous because it also gives access to the Django templating language and all the context of your view, which could have access to server-side secrets.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code but it didn't work, also I think you need .render(Context(context)) so that it's error-free (Django 2.2). However, I am new to web so my logic and approach may be naive (and dangerous as you mentioned), what is a better/common-er way to achieve what I want? i.e. add text and media contents to db and have them auto-processed and displayed on web page.

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661560/django-template-render-from-db-and-interprets-tags