# How to insert dynamic content with Django admin interface

Tags: django-admin

I have a simple model for blog posts with a TextField, I save my posts in html format via Django admin interface. But my posts often include hyperlinks to other blog post pages like `<a href="..">click here</a>`, the number and target of links in a post vary. What is the easy way to insert those urls *dynamically* in Django admin panel (like template tags used in templates)?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I think this can be done with using builtin url tags like `{% url 'blog:posts' 123 %}` in my text, saving the text as a template and rendering it again. Either in the [view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57135568/13787739) or in the template with a [custom template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661819/13787739).